# « Il va continuer d'avoir [quelque chose] » impersonnel ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, oral, pronoms-personnels

> Il va continuer d'avoir [*du développement*, *des questions* etc.].

On trouve parfois cette tournure impersonnelle dans la transcription de propos tenus à l'oral ([1](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/2023-03-30/sante-quebec/collision-entre-legault-et-l-opposition.php), [2](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1512084/chaire-recherche-port-baie-sept-iles-inrest)).

- Devrait-on normalement retrouver le pronom *y* intercalé (*d'y
  avoir*) et si c'est le cas, pourquoi déjà ; s'agit-il d'une ellipse, d'un amuïssement et comment aurait-on pu le marquer le cas échéant ?
- La tournure fonctionnerait-elle avec le pronom *on* indéterminé comme sujet ?

Comment: En France, j'ai toujours lu et entendu "il va continuer d'y avoir". L'absence du "y" est peut-être en usage au Canada !

Comment: Je ne l'ai jamais entendu au Québec sans y.

Answer (score 1):

En français métropolitain écrit, la phrase citée est incorrecte. *Il y a* est une expression figée à sens impersonnel / passif, dans laquelle le *y* est indispensable, y compris dans des tournures dérivées (telles que *il va continuer d’y avoir...*). *Il va continuer d’avoir...* n’est correct que pour un *il* personnel, sujet d’une phrase avec le verbe *avoir* au sens de usuel (par exemple : *il va continuer d’avoir faim* où *il* = Louis, Paul ou Jacques).

La formule *on va continuer d’avoir...* est en revanche entièrement correcte dans la mesure où le *on* a valeur de *nous*. Par exemple

> On va continuer d’avoir des questions gênantes / Il va continuer d’y avoir des questions gênantes

Ici, c’est le locuteur (ou quelqu’un dont il est proche) à qui les questions seront addressées. Par exemple, le locuteur pourrait être conseiller d'une ministre qui refuse de clarifier sa position sur un sujet délicat.

En revanche, dans le sens impersonnel, ce n’est plus possible :

> Il va continuer de pleuvoir (et pas : <s>on va continuer de pleuvoir</s>)

À l’oral, la prononciation de « d’y avoir » serait [di javwaʁ], [di avwaʁ] ou [djavwaʁ]. Il est possible que l’une des deux dernières prononciations (ou les deux) soit fautive ; à titre personnel, aucune des trois ne me choquerait. Je suppose que selon le locuteur, la troisième ([djavwaʁ]) peut être (mal) entendue comme [davwaʁ] (« d'avoir »).

Si le journaliste a effectivement entendu [davwaʁ] (que le propos ait effectivement été tenu ou non), il reste la question de la transcription. En France, je m’attendrais à ce qu’un journaliste corrige ce genre d’erreur orale (très courante, même de la part de l’orateur le plus irréprochable). Pour citer une source sur la pratique hexagonale en la matière, le compte-rendu intégral de l’Assemblée Nationale corrige ce genre d’imprécisions verbales au motif que ce [« n’est pas un mot à mot mais la transposition en langage écrit d’interventions orales »](https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/dyn/15/comptes-rendus/seance). Ce choix peut d’ailleurs poser problème (n’est-on pas en train de modifier les propos tenus ?) mais même une tentative de transcription très fidèle peut rencontrer des problèmes d’ambiguité ([exemple récent](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/parlement-francais/assemblee-nationale/qu-il-s-retourne-nt-en-afrique-comment-des-propos-racistes-ont-fini-par-etre-prononces-a-l-assemblee-nationale_5457871.html)).

(Je suis bien incapable d’indiquer si ce qui précède, en matière de règles ou pratique de la langue ou de culture de transcription, vaut pour le Québec.)